# Google Drive Embed Video unable to control on android

Tags: android, html, css, embed, drive

I embedded a video from my drive to a website it works perfectly on the computer but on my phone im not able to pause or do anything else  with it i tried from other phones its the same Can anyone help??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body style="background-color:#333333;">

<h1 style="color:white;" align="center">Heading</h1>


<div class="videoWrapper">

<p align="center"> <iframe src="link" width="640" height="390" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; 
fullscreen" ></iframe></p>

</div>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show a live example on codepen or something

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in Google where you couldn't pause a video from Drive.
Just make sure that you're using an updated version for Chrome Browser in Mobile, or try a different browser.

I also recommend you to use the tag

```
<video src="/video.mp4" />
```

and try to reproduce the same behavior

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for answering, I tried from other browsers I am able to pause the video but I still can't control it from chrome browser even though it's updated. Maybe the update is not available in my country yet!